# Windows Azure, creating Debian Virtual Machine, problems with provisioning

Tags: azure, debian, virtual-machine, vhd

I've been trying to create new VM on Azure based on Debian Linux and I'm having problems with provisioning. The Azure error is:

"Could not provision the virtual machine"

This is the procedure I used:

1) downloaded last Debian image and installed the base system using Oracle VirtualBox and VHD disk type. I tried with having the swap partition in the VHD and also without swap partition.

2) installed waagent and required components:

```html
apt-get install python
apt-get install python-pyasn1
apt-get install git -y
apt-get install sudo -y
apt-get install parted
git clone https://github.com/Azure/WALinuxAgent
cd WALinuxAgent/
cp waagent /usr/sbin/waagent
chmod 755 /usr/sbin/waagent
/usr/sbin/waagent -install
sudo waagent -force -deprovision
export HISTSIZE=0
logout
```

3) switched off the machine and uploaded it to Azure storage as Page Blob.

4) In Azure made an image using VHD.

5) Made Virtual Machine using user "randomname" and password. Every time I'm getting the error "Could not provision the virtual machine"

Does anybody have the idea what's the solution to this problem?

Thank you
K.

Comment: This should be posted on ServerFault or SuperUser, not StackOverflow. That said: There's more to running a VM on Azure than just creating it locally (there are drivers, etc, which is all documented if you're creating your own image). This is why there are pre-baked Linux VM baseline images already on Azure.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of Debian images [available today](https://vmdepot.msopentech.com/List/Index?search=platform:=debian) on VM Depot. I suggest you take a look at deploying those instead of building your own via commands - and if you need to build your own I suggest you look into [bootstrap-vz](https://github.com/andsens/bootstrap-vz).